# Unable to display image on Whatsapp when sharing a URL link

Tags: image, url, whatsapp

I'm using the following head metatags:

```
<head>
<title>CJF Works Communications</title>
<meta name=”description” content=”The best choice for your marketing needs” /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="CJF Works Communications" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://cjfworks.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="The best choice for your marketing needs" />
<meta property="og:image” itemprop=“image” content=“https://cjfworks.com/logotype-whatsapp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
</head>
```

I am able to display the site title and description but not the image.

Answer (score 0):

Your image isn't big enough.  If you want it to show up on Facebook and Whatsapp it needs to be at least 1200x1200 pixels.  See [Twitter Card - Image not showing - Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104396/twitter-card-image-not-showing/106101#106101)

Comment: I setup a new image at 1200x1206px and made no difference.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 not found error for the image: https://cjfworks.com/logotype-whatsapp.jpg

Comment: If I look at your home page it has `<meta property="og:image" content="https://cjfworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/comm_bubbles.png" />` and that image is only 99x80

Comment: Hello. I'm still unable to display the image. Modified the code as follows:

Comment: Still doesn't work. Not sure about the comm_bubbles.png. No image display. No formatted text on Android devices, only the hyperlink.